# Switching from NATS to RabbitMQ

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I am in the neeed of Switching from NATS messaging system to RabbitMQ.
The current scenario is simple and contains 2 main points:

- anywhere in my code I publish a message of a certain **type**
- all the **subscribers** to that certain **type** handle the message.

I realize that with RabbitMQ and the concept of Queues the situation is a bit different. So my questions are:

1) I need to simulate the same concept above which means throwing different types of messages from different parts of the code. Do I have to create one queue per each kind of message?

2) I cannot create different subscribers to subscribe for the same type of event anymore but I can make them listen to the same queue. Problem is that once a listener receives the message, the message should be market as read and therefore the other subscriber won't receive anything. How do I achieve this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: See [RabbitMQ Fanout Exchange in C# to Publish or Consume Messages](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/rabbitmq/csharp-rabbitmq-fanout-exchange)

Comment: @Theraot nice thank you! So if I understand correctly we can bind queues to a certain fanout exchange. In this way when we send a message to that certain exchange, the exchange itself will broadcast it to all the queues it knows. So this answers one of the two questions. But what about when I want different types of messages? Can I create different fanout exchanges and bind certain queues to a specific exchange?

Comment: I presume that it is possible to do that. However, I have no experience with RabbitMQ. Which is also why I'm not writing an answer.

Comment: @Theraot okey thank you anyway for now!